# Is it valid to store a reference whose lifetime has expired, if the referenced object is still alive?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Is it valid to store a lifetime-bound object (via a raw pointer) for usage for future FFI calls?

Here is a minimal sample:

```rust
struct X(u32);
struct Data<'a> {
    x: &'a mut X,
}

fn create(x: &mut X) -> Data<'_> {
    Data { x }
}

fn main() {
    // Our referenced object, guaranteed not to be destroyed during FFI calls
    let mut x = X(42);

    // First FFI call (just a normal call for this sample)
    let ptr = {
        let xref = &mut x; // start of 'a
        let data = create(xref);
        Box::into_raw(Box::new(data)) as *mut ()
        // end of 'a
    };
    // ptr is returned to the C world

    // Next FFI call, convert the raw pointer back
    let data = unsafe { Box::from_raw(ptr.cast::<Data<'_>>()) };

    // data stores a field having type &'a mut X
    // but the lifetime of the reference it holds ('a) has theoretically expired
    // even if X is guaranteed to still be alive

    // This "works", but is it valid?
    dbg!(data.x.0);
}
```

Assuming we can guarantee that:

- `x` is valid for all FFI calls (so the reference always points to a valid object)
- it is not possible to get 2 references to `x` from safe Rust

Is the code valid?

Or is the "expiration" of the reference lifetime sufficient to make the code invalid? If so, can this be demonstrated (by producing a memory corruption for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Lifetimes are a compile-time-only concept, and "expiration" of borrows doesn't matter for unsafe code. If you make sure to hold the borrow rules (shared xor mutable, and the object wasn't freed) you can safely use the reference even after its lifetime "expired".

Comment: "Lifetimes are a compile-time-only concept": Sure, but compile-time-only concepts could theoretically allow some optimizations which may become invalid if the underlying assumptions are violated from unsafe code. What you are saying is that violating lifetime semantics does not matter (provided that shared xor mutable + valid object if guaranteed), is it correct?

Comment: @rom1v Yes. The borrow checker does not impact the generated code in any way.

Comment: I think this topic is still somewhat debated. See this [post in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/z2jk23/comment/ixlglft/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) about a few lifetime abuses. Although in practice, particularly with FFI it will most likely not affect the OP in any way.

Comment: In fact, the problem I see here is that at the end of the function you could write `*x.0 += 1;` and modify the value while it is mutably borrowed elsewhere. I think that would be UB. Naturally you could just not do that, and then maybe it is ok? Anyway I would feel more comfortable with this code if the `data.x` field were of type `* mut X`.

Comment: @rodrigo This is [UCG issue #231](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/231). It is not _decided_ by the lang team, but I think all members agree on it. I didn't follow the discussion around stack tokens closely, but I don't think it's related.

Comment: Well, the `mk_static()` example cited in Reddit looked a bit like this one. Anyway, I tried the OP code with Miri and, as long as I leave the original `x` alone, Miri is happy. If I modify `x` and then `data.x` it will complain. And using a pointer instead of a reference makes not difference at all.